# Database which increasea every month, which design strategy should I use?

Tags: database, database-design

I have a database that increases every month. The schema remains the same, so I think I use one of these two methods:

- Use only one table, new data will be appended to this table, and will be identified by a date column. The increasing data every month is about 20,000 rows, but in long term, I think this should be problem to search and analyze this data
- create dynamically one table per month, the table name will indicate which data it contains (for example, Usage-20101125), this will force us to use dynamic SQL, but in long term, it seems fine.

I must confess that I have no experiences about designing this kind of database. Which one should I use in real world?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

20 000 rows per month is not a lot. Go with your first option. You didn't mention which database you'll be using, but SQL Server, Oracle, Sybase and PostgreSQL, to name just a few, can handle millions of rows comfortably.

You will need to investigate a proper maintenance plan, including indexing and statistics, but that will come with lots of reading and experience.

Comment: For reference, the largest table I've personally worked with on SQL Server 2005 is 1.5 billion rows.

Comment: wow, it's really impressive. which techniques have you used to archive this?

Comment: As @nate mentioned in his answer, we used table partitioning.

Answer (score 1):

Look into **partitioning** your table.

That way you can physically store the data on different disks for performance while logically it would be one table so your database stays well designed.